# How to change font sizes in Weebly Embed code?

Tags: html, css, weebly

I'm currently doing a school project, and I need to use Weebly to build a website.

Using Weebly's "embed code" section type, I put some code (that I stole off the internet) into the embed code area. The code is basically meant to show text whenever you hover your mouse over an image, however I'm having problems actually changing the font size. When I host it on my ide/browser, Font Size works fine, but when I host it on weebly, the font size is massive (and covers up the image. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,700;);
  .snip1585 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18;
    margin: 10px;
    max-width: 315px;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .snip1585 * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
  }

  .snip1585:before,
  .snip1585:after {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-top: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .snip1585:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(2);
    transform: scaleY(2);
  }

  .snip1585:after {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(2);
    transform: scaleY(2);
  }

  .snip1585 img {
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }

  .snip1585 figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }

  .snip1585 h3 {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .snip1585 h3 span {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  .snip1585 a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
  }

  .snip1585:hover>img,
  .snip1585.hover>img {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }

  .snip1585:hover:before,
  .snip1585.hover:before,
  .snip1585:hover:after,
  .snip1585.hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .snip1585:hover figcaption,
  .snip1585.hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
  }
</style>
<figure class="snip1585">
  <img src="http://www.applet-magic.com/unemploy.jpg" />
  <figcaption>
    <h3>"The first statistic for demonstrating the decline of the economy into depression is the unemployment rate"<span>Courtesy of "San Jose University"(Watkins, The Depression of the 1930's and Its Origins or Causes )</span></h3>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
</html>
```

Comment: Please paste your code in the question itself, not on external sites. Also consider a more descriptive title than "this is not working".

Comment: Choosing the right fonts can take your website from bland to beautiful in an instant. While each theme has default font and color options built in, you’re not stuck with those - you can change the look of virtually any text on your site from the Theme tab. read this documentation below https://hc.weebly.com/hc/en-us/articles/201505666-Edit-Fonts